Finding the value of this sum.
We want to find the value of this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n(n+1)}$ According to Wolfram, tha value is $2 - ln(4)$
What I did :
$\frac{1}{1-x}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$. Differentiation:
$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}$
$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}$ . Integration:
$\frac{1}{(1-x)}+ ln(\vert x-1 \vert) $ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$
$\frac{1}{x(1-x)}
 + \frac{ln(\vert x-1 \vert)}{x} $ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n}}{n+1}$
Doing $x = \frac{1}{2}$, we have the desired series. But the function at $x= \frac{1}{2}$ is $2,61…$, not $2 - ln(4)$
What I am doing wrong?

Are we using $\ln (x-1)=-\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$?

@Gwen I started with the geometric series. Is that your question?

I mean for adding $\ln|x-1|$ in the fourth line, did you apply the power series form?

@Gwen I did integration.

You forgot integration constant. In the fourth line, LHS is $1$ and RHS is $0$ for $x = 0$.

@Riemann Thanks

SImpler (may be) would be to start with $\frac{n x^n}{n+1}=x^n--\frac{x^n}{n+1}$

For all $a > 1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac {k}{k + 1} \cdot \frac {1}{{a}^{k}}
& = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac {k}{{a}^{k}} \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{k} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k \ge 1} k \, {\Big( \frac {x}{a} \Big)}^{k} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k \ge 1} {\bigg[ t \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} {t}^{k} \bigg]}_{t = \frac {x}{a}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} {\bigg[ t \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} \sum_{k \ge 1} {t}^{k} \bigg]}_{t = \frac {x}{a}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} {\bigg[ t \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} \frac {t}{1 - t} \bigg]}_{t = \frac {x}{a}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} {\bigg[ t \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} \Big( \frac {1}{1 - t} - 1 \Big) \bigg]}_{t = \frac {x}{a}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} {\Bigg[ t \cdot \frac {1}{{\left( 1 - t \right)}^{2}} \Bigg]}_{t = \frac {x}{a}} \text {d} x \\
& = a \, \int_{0}^{\frac {1}{a}} \frac {x}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{2}} \text {d} x \\
& = a \, \int_{1 - \frac {1}{a}}^{1} \frac {1 - x}{{x}^{2}} \text {d} x \\
& = a \, \int_{1}^{\frac {a}{a - 1}} \Big( 1 - \frac {1}{x} \Big) \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {a}{a - 1} - a \, \ln \Big( \frac {a}{a - 1} \Big).
\end{align}
$$
In your case, we have $a = 2$.

Clever stuff there!
